# i have created new Java Project, but Eclipse is not showing that project

Tags: java, eclipse

Problem is I have installed new Eclipse and uninstalled the last one.
After Installation, I have created Java project, But Eclipse is not showing that project on Editor.
Means nothing processed.

Can someone help me out.

Comment: refresh it /restart the eclipse/ check the workspace path  is correct

Comment: File > Import from existing source??

Comment: Is the project hide in a working set?

Answer (score 0):

Import your Project into eclipse from 
`FILE -> Import -> Existing Project into Workspace -> browse` and select your project from directory,

And also Do once `Window -> Reset perspective`

Answer (score 0):

You may try

> Windows > Perspective > Open Perspective > **Java Browsing**

from Eclipse.